Fixed Point Iteration Limit Point
This might sound dumb. But I cannot find a plausible answer to this question:
Can fixed point iteration converge to another point than the fixed point of the continuous function?

what do you mean by fixed point iteration? And what function? Be more precise and elaborate.

@psl2Z i mean the sequence ${x_k}$ s.t. $x_{k+1} = f(x_k)$

If $f$ is continuous and iteration $x_{k+1} = f(x_k)$ converges at all, it must converge to a fixed point of $f$ (this is a good exercise, and continuity is necessary). However, it may not converge at all.

What function? What are your assumptions? Be more precise! And use mathjax

@psl2Z Sorry. The only condition is that $f$ is continuous.

The asker specified that $f$ now must be continuous. That makes the answer no.
A sequence converging to $L$ means that for all $\epsilon > 0$ we can find some $N$ such that $\lvert x_{n \geq N} - L \rvert < \epsilon$.
A function $f$ is pointwise continuous if for all $\epsilon > 0$, for any point $x$, we can find some $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert x - x' \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - f(x') \rvert < \epsilon$.
Say our sequence converges: $x_n \to L$, where $f(L) = L'$. Let's fix $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert x - L \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x)-L' \rvert < \epsilon$. Now, let's fix $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, we have $\lvert x_n - L \rvert < \delta$. Now, when we consider the sequence $\{x'_k\}$ where $x'_k = f(x_k)$. Note that each $x'_k$ is at most $\epsilon$ away from $L'$, meaning $x'_k \to L'$. But also, $x'_k = x_{k+1}$. So, for $n \geq N + 1$, we have that $x'_n$ is at most $\epsilon$ away from $L$, which means $x'_k \to L$. A sequence can only converge to one value, so $L' = L$.

Yes. For a function $f$, if you are saying fixed point iteration is the sequence $\{x_k\}$ where $x_{k+1} = f(x_k)$ then with the following choice of $f$:
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^2, x \neq 0 \\
1, x=0
\end{cases}
$$
Look at what happens to our sequence if we start at $0 < x_0 < 1$.

Thanks a lot! Can something like this also happen if $f$ is continuous?

@EnesArda See Qiaochu Yuan in the comments..
